# Unable to connect to ubuntu 20.04 on vm from windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh

I could not manage to make ssh connection working.

ssh user@10.0.2.10
time out…

Port forwarding:

Host ip.   Host port    gast ip.     G-port

0.0.0.0.    2222.      10.0.2.10.   22

Tried with host(windows) private ip
Besides ssh is installed and ufw port 22 opened.
So what is going on here? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by changing from
ssh user@10.0.2.10
To
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost

Basically this port 2222 points to host(windows and not vm itself)
Therefore it is required to be mentioned in a command

And also i had to use localhost instead of vm private ip